# How to read/convert mysql history (.mysql_history) containing \040 instead of whitespace?

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

My .mysql_history looks like:

```
select\040country,\040count(*)\040from\040city_item\040inner\040join\040city\040group\040by\040year,\040country;
```

How to convert it into human readable format? Assuming it is too late to configure `--without-readline` parameter or something else to `my.cfg`

Comment: Usefull when migrating from mysql client to mariadb client.

Answer (score 21):

Use

```
sed "s/\\\040/ /g" < .mysql_history
```